# Charting for an ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

I am just starting a new ASP.NET application. Is it preferable for me to use the MS Charting controls for .NET, as that's already the domain I am using, or is there a real reason to look at other tools such as Google Charts?

Also, I can't seem to find any online/live examples of the MS Charting component online, which makes it a bit difficult to evaluate...

Comment: Specificially addressing Google Charts, you have to generate the numbers (duh), but the actual chart-generation is offloaded to them.  this saves you CPU cycles, similar to the SVG+jSON option @the rebooter mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good tutorial on Microsoft's .NET Chart Control.
http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/microsoft-chart-with-asp-net-35-part1.aspx

While it's good for simple charts, you're better off with a 3rd party control like Telerik's RadCharts for better customizablity & features

Comment: I am actually using Telerik but didn't consider their component... It didn't look great in the screenshots and didn't seem to show up in any forums. Are you recommending it over the MS Charts solution for features only, or also generated look'n'feel?

Comment: Both...the RadCharts have 2 dozen Skins you can pick from..and of course you can customize them even more yourself.  Also the RadCharts are very easy to program against. All it takes is a few settings and a datasource for a simple chart. You can setup advanced features such as a grid & aggregate chart, Ajax updated charts, tooltips, silverlight charts easy too.

Answer (score 0):

You should evaluate SVG+jSON as well. Before you evaluate, you should estimate the load on your web site. Server side charting API's provide very good functionality, but do comsume CPU cycles.If you are expecting a lot of traffic for those pages, you are better off with SVG+jSON for charting. There are [some good jQuery plugins](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html) which can do that for you

Comment: some more jQuery plugins:
http://www.reynoldsftw.com/2009/02/6-jquery-chart-plugins-reviewed/

Answer (score 0):

I am doing a lot of charts and my experience is that you get more and more requirements on the charts and then it is good to have a product that can meet the new requirements so I have used Software FX Chart FX 
http://www.softwarefx.com/

[image]
<sub>(source: [softwarefx.com](http://www.softwarefx.com/SFXPictures/sfxNetProducts/cfxVs2005/newFeatures.gif))</sub>

This is a mature product (like Dundas) and so far I have succeded to create what I want. The test I did with MS Chart worked good and was easy to create the charts but I feel the API is better for Chart FX.
http://demo.softwarefx.com/chartfx/aspnet/ajaxsamples/